# Tower of hanoi with moving from $A$ to $B$, $B$ to $C$ and $C$ to $A$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let in the tower of hanoi's problem, just we can move from $A$ to $B$, $B$ to $C$ and $C$ to $A$. So if we have $n$ disk in the tower $A$. What is the minimal number of mover required to move $n$ disks to tower $C$?

If $a_n$, $b_n$ and $c_n$ are the number of moving from $A$ to $B$, $B$ to $C$ and $C$ to $A$, then what is relation between this sequences and answer of my question? Can you give me a recurrence relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h_n$ and $x_n$ be the number of ways to move $n$ from a tower to 2 next tower and 1 next tower respectively. First we move $n-1$ disks to $C$ and move one disk to $B$ and $n-1$ disks to $A$ and one disk to $C$ and move $n-1$ disks to $C$. So

$$h_n = 2h_{n-1} + x_{n-1} + 2$$

Also if we move $n-1$ disks from $A$ to $C$ and move one disk to $B$ and move $n-1$ disk from $C$ to $B$ (through $A$). So

$$x_n = 2h_{n-1} + 1$$

Note that $h_1 = 2$ and $x_1 = 1$.

So by replace the second relation to the first, we have
$$h_n = 2h_{n-1}+(2h_{n-2}+1)+2$$

Hence

$$
\boxed{h_n=2h_{n-1}+2h_{n-2}+3}\\
h_1=2, h_2 = 7.
$$

Now you can solve this reccurence relation with diffrence methods like generating function!

Answer (score 1):

This particular version of Hanoi Towers has the following recurrence relation:

$$H_n = 3H_{n-1}+2$$

This is proven the same way the typical version of Hanoi Towers recurrence is found. We first move all $n-1$ towers on top of the biggest one from position $A$ to position $C$ in $H_{n-1}$ moves. Then we move the biggest tower from $A$ to $B$. After that we move all $n-1$ towers back to position $A$ in $H_{n-1}$ moves, we again move the biggest tower from $B$ to $C$ and finally we move all $n-1$ towers from $A$ to $C$ in $H_{n-1}$ moves.

This is why $H_n = H_{n-1} + 1 + H_{n-1} + 1 + H_{n-1}= 3H_{n-1}+2$.

If we now solve this recurrence using generating functions we find that $H_n = A3^n+B$ where $A, B\in \mathbb{R}$. We now need some base cases:

- For $n = 1$ we have $2$ moves.
- Using the found recurrence we find that for $n = 2$ we have $8$ moves.

We now solve the following system of equations:

$$3A+B = 2$$
$$9A+B = 8$$
Which gives us $A = 1$ and $B = -1$. Therefore the minimum number of moves we need to make to move all $n$ towers from $A$ to $C$ is:
$$H_n = 3^n-1$$

Comment: If you want me to be more specific when it comes to solving the recurrence (the generating functions part) just ask here in the comments and I'll edit the post.

Comment: I think you were wrong because for n=2, the minimum number of moves is 7 but in your answer for n=2 is 8.